# Magento 404 error but all pages work fine

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, htaccess, 404, not-found

Magento version 1.9.2.4
linux server

I've been having trouble getting my google to crawl my site.

When I run a check on my http header it returns a 404 not found, but I can clearly navigate to the page and it renders fine.

Address: 'atebol.com'

A bit of history on the setup, I originally had the site on a different domain and I enabled web server rewrites. when I changed over I updated the config data with teh base url and cleared the cache. ever since I have been getting a 404 but still able to access my site. for some reason I am not able to turn off server rewrites in the backend, when i do it just says "configuration has been saved" but still says 'yes' in the field.

I have tried swapping out the htaccess with the original htaccess config but has no effect.

can someone please help me, let me know if you need anymore information, thank you.

Comment: You can see that the server is returning a 404 header for every page request.  You'd need to see if this is a server configuration or a Magento issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, I'm not sure exactly why but it was the home cms page that was configuired incorrectly that was causing the problem. I installed a custom home page module and pointed it to that and that solved the problem